# Unable to see completed badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, design, profile-page

I've just noticed that I'm unable to see the badges I've already earned:

[image]

I'm aware that the ["select your next badge" layout previously has had layout issues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317187/select-your-next-badge-layout-issue), but I think this issue is different. I can only see badges I've already earned. Any ideas?

Comment: A fix will be posted today. Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for posting this bug. As **Patrick** pointed out, the problem was the "background-color" had a higher z-index then the text within it. And we could have solved it the way he suggested as well.

However looking at it further we questioned why we even were using a `:before` element here when we can use the `background-color` element? Seeing no reason why we needed to use a before element, we removed it and now are using background-color. Also we've added a hover effect for completed items as well (so you know where your mouse is).

This fix is now posted on production.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is with the `.popup-badges .all-badge-progress .completed:before`. It has a `z-index` of `0`, where `-1` would fit better (the `:before` on the `div` with that class takes care of the background).

If you change that the badges are back:

> [image: unbroken]

Comment: You are absolutely right, good sir

Comment: You are welcome. Just wait with accepting until a developer has fixed the issue. Else they might think it is 'done' already.

Comment: Alrighty, will do. Thanks for notifying me.

Comment: FYI this a network issue.

Comment: You mean, network wide? @dippas

Comment: well ya, a network wide issue :), sorry english is not native language, but I think you understood the message

Comment: Yes, just to be sure :) @dippas